# Energy lost crossing finite potential barrier

Tags: electromagnetism

IF we have a particle with Energy greater than the Energy of the a finite barrier , by finite i mean it is finite in space from x=0 to x=L for example , after it passes it its Energy is E-U , U is the potential of the barrier , now i ask where the lost energy has gone? if the answer is potential energy then how the particle will gain potential Energy if it is outside the domain of the barrier itself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a particle coming from -inf to +inf. At the beginning, it has kinetic energy E. When it is **between** x=0 and x=L , its kinetic energy is E-U. After x=L, it get its potential energy back and its kinetic energy is E again.

You can imagine a ball going up and down a hill.

Comment: 2 comments here : 
1- does the KE returns back to its initial value after crossing the barrier ? if so why in calculating the escape velocity we said at infinity KE will be zero
2- the example u gave of the ball , the ball is already in the domain of the gravitational pull of earth , i speak about after crossing the domain

Comment: 1a - "does the KE returns back to its initial value after crossing the barrier?" Yes if I understood the question and if I am not wrong. 1b - "if so why in calculating the escape velocity we said at infinity KE will be zero?" I understand that by "barrier" you mean the gravitational field o the planet. The gravitational field is not a barrier that is limited at x=L. It acts in a infinite distance. Because of this, you can not think like you did at comment 2. Nothing will never "cross the domain" of the gravitational field.